# Schema.org/Json - Paywall Question regarding customization, properties, medical specifications

Tags: json, schema, schema.org, google-rich-snippets, rich-snippets

Paywalled content must be a property of "Creativework", thats what google says here https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/paywalled-content
so far so good. Im thinking of implementing a paywall on some medical articles and i would like to get a step further from:

```
 "@context": "http://schema.org", 

  "@type": "NewsArticle", 

  "mainEntityOfPage": { 

    "@type": "WebPage", 

    "@id": "https://www.website.com.subpage/" 

  },
```

To:

```
  "@context": "http://schema.org", 

  "@type": "MedicalWebPage", 

  "mainEntityOfPage": { 

    "@type": "WebPage", 

    "@id": "https://www.website.com/subpage/" 

  },
```

Do you think this will work? Is MedicalWebPage a property of CreativeWork? Or do i/must i have to use "Article" or "Newsarticle" for paywalls?

Here the full code i would like to use for the paywall:

```
{ 

  "@context": "http://schema.org", 

  "@type": "MedicalWebPage", 

  "mainEntityOfPage": { 

    "@type": "WebPage", 

    "@id": "https://www.website.com/subpage/" 

  }, 

  "headline": "Headline h1 like Oncology etc", 

  "image": "https://www.website.com/path-to-image.jpg", 

  "datePublished": "2025-02-05T08:00:00+08:00", 

  "dateModified": "2025-02-05T09:20:00+08:00", 

  "author": { 

    "@type": "Person", 

    "name": "John Doe" 

  }, 

  "publisher": { 

     "name": "Medical Organiztion PLC", 

     "@type": "MedicalOrganization", 

     "logo": { 

        "@type": "ImageObject", 

        "url": "https://www.website.com/path-of-a-representative-logo.jpg " 

     } 

  }, 

  "description": "Abstract something like Meta Description", 

  "isAccessibleForFree": "False", 

  "hasPart": 

    { 

    "@type": "WebPageElement", 

    "isAccessibleForFree": "False", 

    "cssSelector" : ".section1” // hidden area must be define in CSS 

    }, 

    { 

    "@type": "WebPageElement", 

    "isAccessibleForFree": "False", 

    "cssSelector" : ".section2" // hidden area must be define in CSS 

    } 

}
```

Comment: What does the page contain? Is it actually a news article (as your first example uses `NewsArticle`)?